# Filter by current date in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How to pass the current date to a query in mysql like such query:

```
select from Dailytimesheet dailytimesheet where dailytimesheet.TrackingDate="2010-05-03"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use `CURRENT_DATE` to get the current date.

```
mysql> select CURRENT_DATE;
+--------------+
| CURRENT_DATE |
+--------------+
| 2010-05-03   |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)
```

Using `NOW()` works as well, but gets you the current date and time as a timestamp value. You can truncate it like `DATE(NOW())`, but `CURRENT_DATE` avoids the function call.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the NOW() function within your SQL query to get the current timestamp.